# How to resolve could not find table 'table name' in Access db

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am inserting new record in a new table in my Access database with the VB.Net code shown below:

```
Try
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = Publicvar.con
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Setting]([PanelName],[UserName],[PassWord],[SmsLineId]) values(@pname,@uname,@pass,@smsLineId)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pname", txtPanelName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("uname", txtUserName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", txtPassWord.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("smsLineId", CInt(txtSmsLineId.Text))

    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("!پنل جدید با موفقیت اضافه شد")
    rgvPanelData.DataSource = PanelClass.Getlistofpanel()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I am faced with this run time error:

> Could not find table Setting

Should I create a new table Setting!

Comment: Thank you for editing my question
Blackwood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [Setting]([PanelName],[UserName],[PassWord],[SmsLineId]) values(@pname,@uname,@pass,@smsLineId)"
```

The **[Setting]** in the above line is the table that the command will insert into.
The Table either needs to preexist in the database or you should create it in your code before trying to insert records into.
You can find [example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) for creating table at runtime.

If your table is not already created, SQL will have no idea of the structure of data that needs to be updated in the DB.

Comment: Hi!
But I am created it in my db and i am confused for this 
why?
Do I Refresh my db ?
how?

Comment: Thank You
solved
I opened my Access and my table there weren't

Comment: if you are still facing this issue, please provide the exact error message. Once you have closed the Access database (application), the changes should automatically reflect.